# How to right align the x_0

Tags: alignment

How can I right align the `x_0` in the image below and how can I right align the `\vdots` which is supposed to be just below the `x_0` in the image?

[image: how cab I right align the \vdots which is supposed to be just below the x_0 in the image]

What I've tried so far is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openany, oneside, 11pt]{report} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{eqnarray*} 
x_\circ(t) &=& x_\circ \\ 
x_1(t)&=& x_\circ + \int_{t_\circ}^{t} f(s, x_\circ(s)) \, ds \\ 
x_2(t)&=& x_\circ + \int_{t_\circ}^{t} f(s, x_1(s)) \, ds \\ 
\vdots \hspace*{0.5cm} \hspace*{-.01cm} & \hspace*{.2cm} \hspace*{-0.001em} \vdots & \hspace*{2.0cm} \vdots \\ 
x_n(t) &=& x_\circ + \int_{t_\circ}^{t} f(s, x_{n-1}(s)) \, ds 
\end{eqnarray*} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried so far.  Incidentally, should that be `x_o` or `x_0`? Why intuition says the latter, but the screenshot you posted says the former.

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper, openany, oneside, 11pt]{report}
\begin{document} 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_\circ(t) &=& x_\circ \\ x_1(t)&=& x_\circ + \int_{t_\circ}^{t} f(s, x_\circ(s)) \, ds \\ x_2(t)&=& x_\circ + \int_{t_\circ}^{t} f(s, x_1(s)) \, ds \\ \vdots \hspace*{0.5cm} \hspace*{-.01cm} & \hspace*{.2cm} \hspace*{-0.001em} \vdots & \hspace*{2.0cm} \vdots \\ x_n(t) &=& x_\circ + \int_{t_\circ}^{t} f(s, x_{n-1}(s)) \, ds
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}

Comment: I've taken the liberty of copying the material in your comment into the main body of the query.

Comment: surely it should be`0` not `\circ` but what do you mean  by "right align" here? do you want the `x_0`  on the first row over on the right above `ds` ??

Comment: Thank you so much @Mico.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. No, I meant. The \vdots should be just in the right position which is where x_0 and not in the equal to sign.

Comment: I would then delete the first part of this sentence, which is very confusing: `How can I right align the x_0 in the image below and how can I right align the \vdots `

Comment: I suspect that "right align" should be read as "correctly align".

Answer (score 6):

Never ever use `eqnarray`.

Here I use `alignat` and `\vdotswithin` of `mathtools`.

I replaced all the `\circ` because I can't stand them, sorry.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openany, oneside, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2} 
x_0(t) &= x_0 \\
x_1(t) &= x_0 &&+ \int_{t_0}^{t} f(s, x_0(s)) \, ds \\
x_2(t) &= x_0 &&+ \int_{t_0}^{t} f(s, x_1(s)) \, ds \\
\vdotswithin{x_n(t)} & \mathrel{\phantom{=}}\vdotswithin{x_0}
&& \mathbin{\phantom{+}} \vdotswithin{\int_{t_0}^{t} f(s, x_1(s)) \, ds} \\
x_n(t) &= x_0 &&+ \int_{t_0}^{t} f(s, x_{n-1}(s)) \, ds
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. I appreciate.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openany, oneside, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 
\begin{align*} 
x_0(t) & =  x_0 \\ 
x_1(t)&= x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t} f(s, x_0(s)) \, ds \\ 
x_2(t)&= x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t} f(s, x_1(s)) \, ds \\ 
\vdots  &\mkern30mu \vdots \mkern60mu \vdots\\ 
x_n(t) & = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t} f(s, x_{n-1}(s)) \, ds 
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The `mathtools` package, which is a superset of the `amsmath` package, provides a macro called `\vdotswithin`; it may be just what you need.

[image]

That said, I can't say I understand why you want to center the third set of `\vdots` on `x_0`. Why not center it on the `+` symbols? You could do so by replacing `\vdotswithin{x_0}` with `\hphantom{x_0} \vdotswithin{+}` in the code shown below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x_0(t) &= x_0 \\
x_1(t) &= x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t} f(s, x_0(s)) \, ds \\
x_2(t) &= x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t} f(s, x_1(s)) \, ds \\
\vdotswithin{x_2(t)} 
       &\vdotswithin{=} \vdotswithin{x_0} \\
x_n(t) &= x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t} f(s, x_{n-1}(s)) \, ds
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It has to be on x_0 since we want to generalize for nth- term.